# Detecting ahk class of YouTube HTML5 player

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to assign **back** and **forward** YouTube keyboard commands to my middle and right click mouse buttons respectively. Unfortunately, with HTML player it is not possible to differentiate the youtube video window from Firefox ahk class as I did before with flash player. I've tried MouseClick commands and simple reassigning keyboard commands to mouse but none of it worked. For some reason autohotkey couldn't be made to send no click commands to the HTML video window and I couldn't even reassign the basic functions of the mouse middle click for example, to make it work as a **Left** keyboard command. 
Anyone has an idea how to make a working autohotkey script that would enable me to turn Left and Right keyboard commands into mouse Right and Middle button clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
#If YouTubeHtml5Active()
    RButton::Right
    MButton::Left
#If

YouTubeHtml5Active() {
    tmmBackup := A_TitleMatchMode 
    SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
    youtubeVideoAvtive := WinActive(".+ \- YouTube \- Mozilla Firefox")
    SetTitleMatchMode, %tmmBackup%
    If youtubeVideoAvtive
        Return True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run on Win10:

> I've tried MouseClick commands and simple reassigning keyboard commands to mouse but none of it worked.

[AutoHotkey in Windows 10 - Hotkeys not working in some applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839062/autohotkey-in-windows-10-hotkeys-not-working-in-some-applications) Some programs need AutoHotkey to be ran in admin mode, otherwise hotkeys are not recognized.

Comment: Hi Blauhirn, no I don't , I'm on Windows 7. I use a few other autohotkey scripts where MouseClick command works perfectly, it is only on youtube that it doesn't work.

Comment: There was a typo in the script, I apologize, it works when I simply assign back and forward commands to middle or right button, but I want this to work only on youtube page, of course, it is not a solution.

Comment: Okay. If it's enough for you that it only works on YouTube pages and not necessarily **only** in HTML5-frames, you can try `#ifWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass, YouTube`

Comment: But if you want to actually detect the "class" of the html5 player itself, as you asked in your question, I don't know either

Comment: Thank you Blauhirn, I've found a working script on the autohotkey forum ( only with WheelUp and WheelDown commands, to scroll up and down), I've posted is as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple script doing this on autohotkey forum http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69720-controll-youtube-volume-with-mousewheel/, here it is, works like a charm:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive YouTube
RButton::Send {Left}
MButton::Send {Right}
return
```

Comment: This would basically override your keys on every window that contains the string "YouTube" and would also set the title match mode for the whole script. (just saying)

Comment: You're right Forivin, the script works but has the problem with carrying over the mouse commands from youtube on other pages occasionally, so not entirely reliable. Your script works perfectly, thank you very much again!