# autohotkey ControlClick does not work on MS tools

Tags: autohotkey

I have a basic AHK script that I am trying to run on a MS tool `SurfaceDiagnosticToolkit.exe`. Trying to click any button does not work.

Steps followed,

1. start SurfaceDiagnosticToolkit.exe
2. select screen with title `Microsoft Surface Diagnostic Toolkit (Fan Test 1/1)`
3. run script below.
   .

   detectHiddenWindows, On;
   WinActivate, Microsoft Surface Diagnostic Toolkit (Fan Test 1/1)
   MouseMove,1255,1190
   MouseClick,Left,1255,1190

The script will bring the window to the front, but the mouse does not move over the screen and the MouseClick does not fire.

Other AHK tools like `WinMove` also do not seem to work.

Interestingly this program shows a green fading bar going left to right on the toolbar icon similar to the copying files icon.

I have also tried with the same results

```
MouseMove, 1560, 40
Send {vk01sc000}
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839062/autohotkey-in-windows-10-hotkeys-not-working-in-some-applications

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for the pointer `run as admin` was the trick!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoHotkey in Windows 10 - Hotkeys not working in some applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839062/autohotkey-in-windows-10-hotkeys-not-working-in-some-applications)