# Close Everything.exe with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I cannot close [Everything.exe](https://www.voidtools.com/) with autohotkey. 
I cant even get the window id using this;

```
if WinExist("ahk_class Notepad") or WinExist("ahk_class" . ClassName)
WinActivate  ; Uses the last found window.

MsgBox % "The active window's ID is " . WinExist("A")
Return
```

it should return similar to this which all other apps on PC do!

```
The Active Windows ID is 0x013017e
```

I have already tried

```
StartClose("Everything.exe")

StartClose(exe)
    {
    Process, Exist, %exe% ; check to see if program is running
    If (ErrorLevel = 0) ; If program is not running -> Run
    {
    Run, %exe%
     }
 Else ; If program is running, ErrorLevel = process id for the target program -> 
 Close
    {
     Process, Close, %ErrorLevel%
     }
 }
 return
```

and this

Process, Close, Everything.exe

Process, Close, ahk_class EVERYTHING

Process, Close, ahk_exe Everything.exe

Help!

Comment: Everything has two processes, one for the service running in the background, and the other for the UI. For me, `Process, Exist` returns the PID of the service, which is running in the SYSTEM context and therefore fails to close unless you run AHK as SYSTEM.

Comment: maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839062/autohotkey-in-windows-10-hotkeys-not-working-in-some-applications

Answer (score -1):

```
CloseProcess(PidOrExe){
    Processes:=ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
    for Process in Processes
        If (Process.Name=PidOrExe || Process.ProcessID=ParentPidOrExe)
            Process,Close,% process.ProcessID 
}
```

Comment: This just uses a convoluted "Process,Close,%" method, which I stated that I have tried.